# The setup files are corrupted. Please obtain a new copy of the program

Tags: windows-8

Whenever i open my pc,there is a message that "The setup files are corrupted. Please obtain a new copy of the program". But i don't know which setup files are corrupted. how to resolve it?

Comment: Turn off all programs in start up and see if that helps. Then turn them on one at time. Same for in Task Scheduler. See if Event Viewer helps

Comment: You should use AutoRuns to identify the program.

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible solutions to this problem may be moving the file to the location with no special characters. For instance, I have tried to install the drivers for Pedal(Flamma FX100), and it was constantly throwing me this type of error.

The problem was in the complete path to the setup file. I had my Windows username in Russian, while the system language was in English.
The fix: `moved the setup file to the root directory of D:/` drive and ran it again. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You question is not very clear so I am going to take a stab in the dark.

I assume this is when you start your computer up and is showing a message on the screen. If you can click ok or cancel and then use the computer as usual it is likely a third party application. You could disable and enable each one to work out which it is if it gives you no clues.

- Press the windows key and r together, or find 'Run' in the start menu, type msconfig and press enter
  under services tick hide all Microsoft services and then disable
  everything else (apart from your AV) under startup click open in task
  manager and set everything to disable restart and see if you still
  get the message

If you don't enable a few at a time till you get the error again